# CSS Div / Box Font Issue

Tags: css, fonts, html

Having a weird error in a CSS box. I'm getting large spacing between paragraph tags:

[image]

As you can see, there is multiline spacing between the headers and paragraphs

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="exampleboxshadowf">
<span class="examplelabelboxshadow">

<h1>Introduction</h1>
<p>Some info</p>
<h1><em>Location, Location</em></1>
<p>More Info</p>
```

The CSS for the box is:

```
div.exampleboxshadowf {
background-color: #eee;
position:fixed;
top:30px;
left:100px;
float:none;
margin-top: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 575px;
width:840px;
text-align: center;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

And I've set the font and p, h tags like:

```
h1 {
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Noticia Text';
}

h2 {
font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'Noticia Text';

}

p {
font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Noticia Text';

}

body, span {
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
```

Noticia Text is a Google font which is imported and I can confirm is working correctly.

Any idea what is causing such weird spacing?

Comment: Inspect the style of the elements and check for things like `line-height`, `padding` and `margin`.

Comment: This JSBin http://jsbin.com/idahef/1/ seems to have normal spacing, so it is either the font or additional styles you have. As Tim mentions above, inspect the elements and see what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Specify margins for `h1` and `h2`, as well as the `<p>`. Also note that when you have `position: fixed`, you do not need margins. Here's the code:

```
div.exampleboxshadowf {
     background-color: #eee;
     position:fixed;
     top:30px;
     left:100px;
     overflow: scroll;
     height: 575px;
     width: 840px;
     text-align: center;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
             box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888
}
div.exampleboxshadowf h1 {
     font-size: 16px;
     font-family: 'Noticia Text';
     margin: 5px auto
}
div.exampleboxshadowf h2 {
     font-size: 18px;
     font-family: 'Noticia Text';
     margin: 5px auto
}
div.exampleboxshadowf p{
     margin: 5px
}
```